# Greek alphabet not displayed correctly in tikzpicture mode

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, greek, timeline

I'm using the package Ti*k*Z to make a timeline with arrows and text pointing to certain ticks. (`\begin{tikzpicture}`...)

The text I have inside the `\addmilestone{...}` environment contains the Greek letter lower case `\xi` which it displays as something that resembles a number "6". The `\xi`'s in the rest of the document outside of Ti*k*Z environment display correctly.

Any ideas how I can fix this? Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{timeline}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[timespan={}]
\timeline[custom interval=true]{, , , , , }
\begin{phases}
\phase{between week=1 and 2 in 0.7,involvement degree=2.125cm}
\end{phases}
\addmilestone{at=phase-1.90,direction=60:1cm,text={decision},text options={above}}
\addmilestone{at=phase-1.270,direction=330:1cm,text={$\xi_j$, $F_{\xi_1,\xi_2}$, $F_{\eta}$},text options={below}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please, show us the code you are using.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! In its present form your question is unanswerable, and will be closed after some grace period. Please do what @Sigur is suggesting: provide us with a minimal example that shows the problem, i.e. a document that starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}` and illustrates the issue.

Comment: While you don’t give enough information to reproduce this bug, I note that, in the OML encoding, ξ is `"18`. In T1, You might be displaying the glyph in this slot from another 8-bit font,

Comment: Probably, using `\usetikzlibrary {babel}` in the preamble solves the problem. But you still need to add MWE as @marmot points out.

Comment: \documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{timeline}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[timespan={}]


\timeline[custom interval=true]{, , , , , }


\begin{phases}

\phase{between week=1 and 2 in 0.7,involvement degree=2.125cm}


\end{phases}

\addmilestone{at=phase-1.90,direction=60:1cm,text={decision},text options={above}}
\addmilestone{at=phase-1.270,direction=330:1cm,text={$\xi_j$, $F_{\xi_1,\xi_2}$, $F_{\eta}$},text options={below}}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Comment: I've added the code - thank you! As you can see, $\eta$ displays properly but $\xi$ does not. I tried adding \usetikzlibrary {babel} to the preamble also. Same issue when I insert the code inside a document class of article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the library from https://github.com/cfiandra/timeline

As I suspected, the code contains a bad part that affects `\xi`. Open `tikzlibrarytimeline.code.tex` and replace all occurrences of `\xi` with `\tlxi`.

[image]

Comment: Filed issue at https://github.com/cfiandra/timeline/issues/3

Comment: Fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/cfiandra/timeline/commit/92c51b587ab82efa395cd25ceb37bdbd64449f68). Thanks @egreg :)

Comment: Thanks so much!